# Two "else" statements in a bash script?

Tags: shell-script

I have an `sshfs` mount from a remote server that breaks every once in a while due to connectivity issues.  To fix this, I have written a script to check if a file exists on the mount, and if not to email me AND reconnect with `sshfs`.

I am not sure whether I have the right syntax on the second statement after `else`.  Not sure if I need brackets to separate them or a semicolon to end the first statement?  Here is the code:

```
#!/bin/bash
file="/path/to/mount/.exists"
if [ -f "$file" ]

then

echo "$file found." > /dev/null 2>&1

else
/usr/sbin/sendmail -t alert-email@foo.com </etc/alert.txt

/bin/sh /etc/fix_mount.sh
fi
```

After the `else`, I am first sending the warning message to let us know it happened and then executing a second bash script to reconnect `sshfs`.  I know that `/etc/fix_mount.sh` works on its own, but I'm afraid the `else` won't execute properly because of my syntax.  Brackets?  Semicolon? Is it already OK?

Comment: I can see nothing wrong with your syntax. Is the script working?

Comment: Your syntax is fine. Spend more time with bash and you'll be great. I want to address something else though, are you aware of the `ServerAliveInterval` option to ssh? It makes it ping the server every so often, and depending on the type of network failure may be helpful. (You would use something like `sshfs -o ssh_command "ssh -o ServerAliveInterval=30" ...` (I think) to use this.)  Beyond this, `sshfs` also has `-o reconnect` to automatically reconnect, this may be useful as well.

Comment: I have had the second else statement live for only 24 hours, most likely the connection to the remote mount will not break for months (it's a pretty rare occurence) and I don't want to "test" breaking it because it takes an important website offline.  I thought the syntax might already be OK, so if you thinks so too, that's good enough for me!  Thanks so much!

Answer (score 2):

Your syntax is fine.

The syntax for an if/then/else statement includes key words: `if`, `then`, `else`, and `fi` (let's not forget `elif`). The commands after the `then`, `else`, and `elif` statements are allowed to be a *list* of commands (one or more commands).

Comment: The part after `if` can also be a list of commands. `if read x; [ "$x" = "" ]; then echo "empty string"; fi` is fine. It's probably more useful with `while`, though.

Answer (score 1):

Looks OK to me, although I would have written it something like:

```
#!/bin/bash

check_file="/path/to/mount/.exists"

if [ ! -f "$check_file" ]; then 
    /usr/sbin/sendmail -t alert-email@foo.com </etc/alert.txt
    /bin/sh /etc/fix_mount.sh
fi
```

I see no reason for the first `echo` statement since you are directing it to `/dev/null`.

And it makes more sense to act if the file is **not** present. Hence the logical not `!` operator.

Also, I would avoid using `file` as a variable name since it is a [GNU/Linux program](https://linux.die.net/man/1/file).

However, as your script stands, it *should* work.